Unable to receive events in durable suborchestrator function (isolated model)
I am trying to wait for external event in suborchestrator function. Test shows that event sent to main orchestrator ID can be received in main orchestrator but not in suborchestrator.
I speculated that events are not received because they are sent to instance id of main orchestrator but if I want to send even to suborchestrator instance ID, I can't see an easy way of figuring out what suborchestrator instance ID is. In isolated model TaskOrchestrationContext does not offer passing instance id to suborchestrator start function. I guess once suborchestrator function starts, it can send event to main orchestrator with its ID but this looks to be strange and convoluted implementation.
Code below exposes Jobs_HttpStart_Event to start the orchestrator sending events.

using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DurableFuncExperiment
{
    public static class Function
    {
        public record EventData(string instanceId, string eventName, string data);

        public const string SayHelloOrchestrator = "Jobs_SayHello";
        public const string SayHelloOneActivitity = "Jobs_SayHelloOne";
        public const string SayHelloEventOrchestrator = "Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator";
        public const string SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator = "Jobs_SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator";

        
        // Leave SayHello for experiments if needed

        [Function(SayHelloOrchestrator)]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(SayHelloOrchestrator);
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello.");
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            // Replace name and input with values relevant for your Durable Functions Activity
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(SayHelloOneActivitity, "Tokyo"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(SayHelloOneActivitity, "Seattle"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(SayHelloOneActivitity, "London"));

            // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
            return outputs;
        }

        const string EventName = "EventToWaitFor";

        [Function(SayHelloEventOrchestrator)]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunSayHelloEventOrchestrator(
          [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context,
          [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient durableTaskClient)
        {
            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(SayHelloOrchestrator);
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello.");
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            // Replace name and input with values relevant for your Durable Functions Activity

            var task = context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator);

            await context.CreateTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), CancellationToken.None);

            await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(RaiseEventActivity), new EventData(context.InstanceId, EventName, "Data"));
            await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(RaiseEventActivity), new EventData(context.InstanceId, EventName, "Data"));


            var eventValue = await context.WaitForExternalEvent<string>(EventName);
            logger.LogInformation($"Event received by main orchestration: {eventValue}");

            await task;

            logger.LogInformation($"Sub orchestration finished and was awaited succesfully");


            return outputs;
        }

        [Function(SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator)]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunSayHelloEventSubOrchestrator(
       [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(SayHelloOrchestrator);
            logger.LogInformation($"RunSayHelloEventSubOrchestrator started. InstanceId={context.InstanceId}");
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            var eventValue = await context.WaitForExternalEvent<string>(EventName);

            logger.LogInformation($"Event received by sub orchestration: {eventValue}");

            return outputs;
        }


        [Function(nameof(SayHelloOneActivitity))]
        public static string SayHelloOne([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SayHello");
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [Function(nameof(RaiseEventActivity))]
        public static async Task RaiseEventActivity([ActivityTrigger] EventData eventData, [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("RaiseEventActivity");
            logger.LogInformation($"raising event {eventData}");
            await client.RaiseEventAsync(instanceId: eventData.instanceId, eventName: eventData.eventName, eventPayload: eventData.data);
        }

        [Function("Jobs_HttpStart_Event")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> Jobs_HttpStart_Event(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Jobs_HttpStart_Event");

            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
                SayHelloEventOrchestrator);

            logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

            // Returns an HTTP 202 response with an instance management payload.
            // See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#start-orchestration
            return await client.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId);
        }


    }
}


Log ends with main orchestrator receiving an event. Suborchestrator hangs forver.
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-07-02T04:06:42.063Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000000C75A72E'.
[2024-07-02T04:06:51.223Z] Executing 'Functions.Jobs_HttpStart_Event' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=86ba1f8b-9454-4158-9e7a-d1316a7a1140)
[2024-07-02T04:06:51.858Z] Scheduling new Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator orchestration with instance ID 'd0e8390352d1403b88e6fb763a33cbb2' and 0 bytes of input data.
[2024-07-02T04:06:52.116Z] Started orchestration with ID = 'd0e8390352d1403b88e6fb763a33cbb2'.
[2024-07-02T04:06:52.239Z] Executed 'Functions.Jobs_HttpStart_Event' (Succeeded, Id=86ba1f8b-9454-4158-9e7a-d1316a7a1140, Duration=1056ms)
[2024-07-02T04:06:52.272Z] Executing 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=91ac3cd9-504b-4a6e-81f4-b55a4febdcc2)
[2024-07-02T04:06:52.507Z] Saying hello.
[2024-07-02T04:06:52.587Z] Executed 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=91ac3cd9-504b-4a6e-81f4-b55a4febdcc2, Duration=341ms)
[2024-07-02T04:06:52.729Z] Executing 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=52250685-de55-4753-9eb5-a119bb2f14c1)
[2024-07-02T04:06:52.768Z] RunSayHelloEventSubOrchestrator started. InstanceId=2236b5d8ffd15b7b9180de5d977309da
[2024-07-02T04:06:52.781Z] Executed 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=52250685-de55-4753-9eb5-a119bb2f14c1, Duration=54ms)
[2024-07-02T04:07:08.919Z] Executing 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=cf21b5f6-0582-4f7e-bfe8-bd7d2fe10fef)
[2024-07-02T04:07:08.979Z] Executed 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=cf21b5f6-0582-4f7e-bfe8-bd7d2fe10fef, Duration=61ms)
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.023Z] Executing 'Functions.RaiseEventActivity' (Reason='(null)', Id=afdcb70b-6f35-4b1e-a87d-72929ac86192)
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.041Z] raising event EventData { instanceId = d0e8390352d1403b88e6fb763a33cbb2, eventName = EventToWaitFor, data = Data }
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.100Z] Executed 'Functions.RaiseEventActivity' (Succeeded, Id=afdcb70b-6f35-4b1e-a87d-72929ac86192, Duration=81ms)
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.115Z] Executing 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=71444a03-da20-4325-b60f-dba7bfe5b86e)
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.149Z] Executed 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=71444a03-da20-4325-b60f-dba7bfe5b86e, Duration=36ms)
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.203Z] Executing 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=81b80312-48f0-4aba-8d42-4a9fd384966b)
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.238Z] Executed 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=81b80312-48f0-4aba-8d42-4a9fd384966b, Duration=35ms)
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.264Z] Executing 'Functions.RaiseEventActivity' (Reason='(null)', Id=e8417808-7b31-41fc-bdbc-87358e714c9b)
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.286Z] raising event EventData { instanceId = d0e8390352d1403b88e6fb763a33cbb2, eventName = EventToWaitFor, data = Data }
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.334Z] Executed 'Functions.RaiseEventActivity' (Succeeded, Id=e8417808-7b31-41fc-bdbc-87358e714c9b, Duration=70ms)
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.352Z] Executing 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=44627a58-4494-4099-a5b5-435bf1a4b994)
[2024-07-02T04:07:09.373Z] Executed 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=44627a58-4494-4099-a5b5-435bf1a4b994, Duration=20ms)
[2024-07-02T04:07:12.545Z] Executing 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=9b3d7f92-a6fe-4ffb-b072-8fbca7a03c6f)
[2024-07-02T04:07:12.561Z] Event received by main orchestration: Data
[2024-07-02T04:07:12.567Z] Executed 'Functions.Jobs_SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=9b3d7f92-a6fe-4ffb-b072-8fbca7a03c6f, Duration=22ms)



I speculated that events are not received because they are sent to instance id of main orchestrator but if I want to send even to suborchestrator instance ID.


Yes, indeed because the event is being raised for main orchestrator with the instance id of it but not for sub orchestrator in the code.
I believe, you can only raise the events to the orchestration which is running RaiseEventActivity.
So instead of raising events from main orchestration, you can directly raise it in sub-orchestration.
In the below code, I am raising the event in sub-orchestration and getting expected response.

using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _78695020
{
    public static class Function1
    {

        public record EventData(string instanceId, string eventName, string data);

        [Function("SayHelloOrchestrator")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(Function1));
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello.");
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            // Replace name and input with values relevant for your Durable Functions Activity
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(("SayHelloOneActivitity"), "Tokyo"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(("SayHelloOneActivitity"), "Seattle"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(("SayHelloOneActivitity"), "London"));

            // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
            return outputs;
        }

        const string EventName = "EventToWaitFor";

        [Function("SayHelloEventOrchestrator")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunSayHelloEventOrchestrator(
          [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context,
          [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient durableTaskClient)
        {
            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger("SayHelloOrchestrator");
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello.");
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            var task = context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator");

            await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(RaiseEventActivity), new EventData(context.InstanceId, EventName, "Main Data"));

            await context.CreateTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), CancellationToken.None);
            var eventValue = await context.WaitForExternalEvent<string>(EventName);
            logger.LogInformation($"Event received by main orchestration: {eventValue}");

            await task;
            logger.LogInformation($"Sub orchestration finished and was awaited succesfully");

            return outputs;
        }

        [Function("SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator")]
        public static async Task<string> RunSayHelloEventSubOrchestrator(
       [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger("SayHelloOrchestrator");
            logger.LogInformation($"RunSayHelloEventSubOrchestrator started. InstanceId={context.InstanceId}");
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(RaiseEventActivity), new EventData(context.InstanceId, EventName, "Sub Data"));
            var eventValue = await context.WaitForExternalEvent<string>(EventName);
            logger.LogInformation($"Event received by sub orchestration: {eventValue}");

            return eventValue;
        }


        [Function("SayHelloOneActivitity")]
        public static string SayHelloOne([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SayHello");
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [Function(nameof(RaiseEventActivity))]
        public static async Task RaiseEventActivity([ActivityTrigger] EventData eventData, [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("RaiseEventActivity");
            logger.LogInformation($"raising event {eventData}");
            await client.RaiseEventAsync(instanceId: eventData.instanceId, eventName: eventData.eventName, eventPayload: eventData.data);
        }

        [Function("Jobs_HttpStart_Event")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> Jobs_HttpStart_Event(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1_HttpStart");

            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync("SayHelloEventOrchestrator");

            logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

            // Returns an HTTP 202 response with an instance management payload.
            // See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#start-orchestration
            return await client.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}

I am getting given response.
Functions:

        Jobs_HttpStart_Event: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7006/api/Jobs_HttpStart_Event

        RaiseEventActivity: activityTrigger

        SayHelloEventOrchestrator: orchestrationTrigger

        SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator: orchestrationTrigger

        SayHelloOneActivitity: activityTrigger

        SayHelloOrchestrator: orchestrationTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-07-22T13:36:45.820Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000BF6D1ED5'.
[2024-07-22T13:36:57.713Z] Executing 'Functions.Jobs_HttpStart_Event' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=75c73068-aefc-4c85-abdd-69681bcec518)
[2024-07-22T13:36:57.994Z] Scheduling new SayHelloEventOrchestrator orchestration with instance ID 'fcfbaea24c82443699eb37af22e567bd' and 0 bytes of input data.
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.143Z] Started orchestration with ID = 'fcfbaea24c82443699eb37af22e567bd'.
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.209Z] Executed 'Functions.Jobs_HttpStart_Event' (Succeeded, Id=75c73068-aefc-4c85-abdd-69681bcec518, Duration=516ms)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.234Z] Executing 'Functions.SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=46ca3ad2-5a5f-44d3-b55c-3e740ded8604)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.344Z] Saying hello.
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.384Z] Executed 'Functions.SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=46ca3ad2-5a5f-44d3-b55c-3e740ded8604, Duration=163ms)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.434Z] Executing 'Functions.SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=31ce7593-1778-41ac-9dbd-928db70f390c)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.438Z] Executing 'Functions.RaiseEventActivity' (Reason='(null)', Id=40ef0eb8-ec7b-47d0-bbc5-175177a10b1b)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.440Z] RunSayHelloEventSubOrchestrator started. InstanceId=888c79f447e655cea735c827024a5dd3
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.445Z] Executed 'Functions.SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=31ce7593-1778-41ac-9dbd-928db70f390c, Duration=12ms)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.449Z] raising event EventData { instanceId = fcfbaea24c82443699eb37af22e567bd, eventName = EventToWaitFor, data = Main Data }
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.475Z] Executing 'Functions.RaiseEventActivity' (Reason='(null)', Id=42821443-fb84-43a3-ba5d-6fbb72fe936b)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.511Z] raising event EventData { instanceId = 888c79f447e655cea735c827024a5dd3, eventName = EventToWaitFor, data = Sub Data }
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.519Z] Executed 'Functions.RaiseEventActivity' (Succeeded, Id=40ef0eb8-ec7b-47d0-bbc5-175177a10b1b, Duration=85ms)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.525Z] Executing 'Functions.SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=4e388b41-bce4-4fa9-9946-acdf1395fee0)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.527Z] Executed 'Functions.RaiseEventActivity' (Succeeded, Id=42821443-fb84-43a3-ba5d-6fbb72fe936b, Duration=51ms)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.540Z] Executing 'Functions.SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=55a26bb7-a0b9-4f40-9da2-aa4ad957a1a4)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.541Z] Executed 'Functions.SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=4e388b41-bce4-4fa9-9946-acdf1395fee0, Duration=18ms)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.547Z] Executed 'Functions.SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=55a26bb7-a0b9-4f40-9da2-aa4ad957a1a4, Duration=7ms)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.561Z] Executing 'Functions.SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=df40048a-0487-40a4-9082-8a20a1074604)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.562Z] Executing 'Functions.SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=c5db05df-c783-491d-ba84-b21a76ae675d)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.571Z] Event received by sub orchestration: Sub Data
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.577Z] Executed 'Functions.SayHelloEventSubOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=c5db05df-c783-491d-ba84-b21a76ae675d, Duration=14ms)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.579Z] Executed 'Functions.SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=df40048a-0487-40a4-9082-8a20a1074604, Duration=18ms)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.616Z] Executing 'Functions.SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=495c0125-3839-4dbd-a044-fc6903fb075a)
[2024-07-22T13:36:58.627Z] Executed 'Functions.SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=495c0125-3839-4dbd-a044-fc6903fb075a, Duration=11ms)
[2024-07-22T13:37:23.429Z] Executing 'Functions.SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=0ef17032-4ec4-4cfe-8214-d8b06cdff0a4)
[2024-07-22T13:37:23.440Z] Event received by main orchestration: Main Data
[2024-07-22T13:37:23.441Z] Sub orchestration finished and was awaited succesfully
[2024-07-22T13:37:23.447Z] Executed 'Functions.SayHelloEventOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=0ef17032-4ec4-4cfe-8214-d8b06cdff0a4, Duration=19ms)


I was hoping to get interaction between parent and sub orchestrations going. For example, parent could signal child when to stop or post some data to be processed. As you can imagine, sending events to itself is not very valuable thing to be able to do: might as well simply restart using ContinueAsNew with parameter.

@VladimirGaytanov I understood your requirement but in the parent orchestration, we are raising event by using its instance I'd so event is not being passed to child. We can pass the instance I'd of child orchestration in parent

that's a big complaint of mine: API does not seem to expose sub orchestration instance id. As a result, one can't interact with sub orchestration by means of events. so close and yet so far.

Yes, I believe the feature to raise the event for a child orchestration inside parent orchestration yet to be added by the product team. So for now I would suggest you to raise it in child orchestration itself.

TaskOptions has this method that is meant to enable creating suborchestrations with given ID. This should enable sending events from parent orchestration to suborchestration.
public SubOrchestrationOptions WithInstanceId(string instanceId)

